# javax validation based on operation

Tags: java, spring, validation

I am trying to use javax validations on DTO. But I want these validations to be applied based on the operation for which this DTO is used.

Lets say I have the following DTO:

```
@Getter @Setter
public class CustomerDTO {

    @NotNull
    private String id;

    @NotNull 
    private String name;
}
```

I am using the same DTO for Create, Update and Delete operations. 
Incase of Update and Delete operation I want "id" to be NotNull, but in Create it has to be null.

But since I am using the same DTO, and on using @Valid annotation at controller level, it applies to all the attributes. And the following API fails as "id" cannot be null

```
public CustomerDTO createCustomer(@Valid CustomerDTO customer, BindingResults results){
    if(results.hasErrors()){
        throw IllegalArgumentsException("Required params are mising");
    }
    customerService.create(customer);
}
```

Comment: I suggest instead of trying to [Update and Delete operation Not Null with javax], remove @NotNull annotation at id and make NOT NULL constraints at your DB, and then check condition (id not null)at Update and Delete operation.

Comment: Thanks Alice. I am actually trying to build a framework, as there are a lot entities in our product.I do have NOT NULL constraints in DB. Using javax.validation it removes a lot of boiller plate code and it even supports localized error messages.

Comment: Create a separate classes InsertCustomerDTO and UpdateCustomerDTO extending the same BaseCustomerDTOand add desired validation in the classes.

Comment: Thanks StanislavL. I cannot create separate DTOs for all the entities x operations.

Answer (score 11):

Since you are using Spring, you can use its `@Validated` annotation and system.

How it works: every validation annotation has a field `groups`. This field allows you to determine when the validation should be done, based on a class. What you can do is the following:

1. Create a `ValidationGroups` class with all validation groups you need. Example:

```
import javax.validation.groups.Default;

/**
 * Utility classes to distinct CRUD validations.<br>
 * <br>
 * Used with the
 * {@link org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated @Validated}
 * Spring annotation.
 */
public final class ValidationGroups {

    private ValidationGroups() {
    }

    // Standard groups

    public interface Create extends Default {};
    public interface Replace extends Default {};
    public interface Update extends Default {};
    public interface Delete extends Default {};
}
```

2. For your case, annotate your `id` field like the following:

```
@Null(
    groups = Create.class
)
@NotNull(
    groups = { Update.class, Delete.class }
)
private String id;
```

3. Finally, tell controller-side which group(s) you want to validate with the `@Validated` annotation rather than the `@Valid` one:

```
public CustomerDTO createCustomer(@Validated(Create.class) CustomerDTO customer, BindingResult results) {
    if(results.hasErrors()){
        throw IllegalArgumentsException("Required params are mising");
    }
    customerService.create(customer);
}

// Etc. You can put multiple groups like @Validated({ Update.class, Delete.class })
```

**NOTE** about the `extends javax.validation.groups.Default` in `ValidationGroups`:

If you don't extend your `Create` class with `javax.validation.groups.Default`, the validation rule will not be done if you use the `@Validated` annotation without argument.

```
// @Validated without argument validate every annotation with the "Default" group
public void test(@Validated MyForm form, BindingResult results) {
    // ...
}
```

You can inherit validation. For example if you want your `Replace` to validate all your `Create` validation rules, make `Replace`inherit `Create`.

```
public interface Create extends Default {};
public interface Replace extends Create {};
```

Comment: field groups are very useful than I thought!

Comment: Thanks kagmole. This is exactly what I was looking for. Will try this out.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't call the `validate` method if the operation being called is 'create'. Alternately, if you must validate the other fields in your DTO, populate a dummy value for the 'id' which you can disregard after calling `validate`.

Comment: Thanks VHS. This may not be the right way of doing it.